# How can we forward *this?

Tags: c++, templates, c++23

As [cppreference says](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#member_functions_with_ref-qualifier):

> unlike cv-qualification, ref-qualification does not change the properties of the `this` pointer: within an rvalue ref-qualified function, `*this` remains an lvalue expression.

Then, how can we get the ref-qualifier of `*this`, or how can we forward `*this`, to avoid repeating to implement the same member function with different ref-qualifier?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Because `*this` stays an lvalue, you can use it like any other lvalue when it comes to references. Like `auto& ref_to_this = *this;` or `auto&& generic_ref_to_this = *this;`.

Comment: You have to override the function 4 times with different ref-qualifiers - 8 if you also care about `volatile`

Comment: @user253751 is using macros the only way to avoid repetition ?

Comment: I think so. And that is one reason you might want to use non-member functions as much as possible - you can use a template type for the-parameter-formerly-known-as-`*this`

Answer (score 6):

In C++23, you can use the [deducing this](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p0847r7.html) language feature to declare the object parameter as a first class function parameter:

```cpp
struct C {
    // roughly equivalent to today's:
    //    void f() const&
    void f(this C const& self);
};
```

This lets you then deduce its type and, thus, forward it, same as any other function parameter that is a forwarding reference:

```cpp
struct C {
    template <typename Self>
    void f(this Self&& self);
};
```